# Cannot run WebRole on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, service, azure-web-roles

I've deployed my Azure Cloud Service with `ParseWebRole` in it.
But when I try to follow my service link I get

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

WepRole is running and the deployment was successful.
I tried to use remote debug to understand what is going on there but it didn't help me. Also I create logger

```
        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Info("Trying to start PrserWebRole...");
                var res =  base.OnStart();
                if (res) _logger.Info("PrserWebRole successfully started!");
                else _logger.Info("PrserWebRole not started!");
                return res;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

In my logger file I don't see any of this messages, I'm pretty sure that my logger is working correctly. 
I had some issues with certificates but I don't think it could had some impact on my problem since I get successful deployment.

Where should I start now? 
And what is the first file that is launching by Azure? Can I debug it?

P.S. Sorry for my English guys ;)